# .htaccess redirection not working

Tags: .htaccess, symfony1

I try to redirect http://mydomain.com to http://www.mydomain.com

I add this to my htaccess file, but it not work :

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.fr [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.fr/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This is the complete file :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.fr [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.fr/$1 [L,R=301]

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: yes, I use Symfony, and my urls are rewrting

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.fr/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I'm using this on an existing site at the moment - seems to work fine here.

Comment: You're going to need to be a bit more specific than "it doesn't work". Have you checked Apache logs? What do they say? We're going on not much information here...

Answer (score 0):

```
  # Never keep domain name without subdomain
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.fr$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.fr/$1 [R=301,L]
```